# Visual Studio Post-build event: for %f in (set) command

Tags: .net, visual-studio, post-build, for-in-loop

This command in the Visual Studio 2010 Post-build event

```
for %f in ("$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.dll") do echo %f
```

(`echo` will be replaced with some other tool) gives me the error

```
The command "[...]" exited with code 255.
```

I guess I have to escape the outermost round brackets but I don't know how. I tried `\(` and `((`.

Comment: why go into dos? why not use msbuild for your post-build event?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might need to use %%f instead of %f for the first one (and maybe the second one).  In a batch file (which VS might use to implement these custom build steps), you have to use the extra % for identifiers.

Edit: here's the first part of the output from `help for` on the command line.

> Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.
>
> FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
>   (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
>   command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
>   command-parameters
>              Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.
>
> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
>   from %I.